# Keeping specific ViewPager pages in memory

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with multiple views in it. When certain conditions are met, the I `setCurrentItem` the ViewPager back to view 0. The application hangs a little this happens, and this lag disappears when I use `setOffscreenPageLimit` to force all views to always be in memory. However, I would like to avoid having to keep all views in memory, as this works well enough for testing purposes, but it is a waste of resources, as I eventually intend to have multiple fairly resource intensive views in it. However, I would like to avoid the lag when jumping back to view 0. Is there a way to ensure that specifically view 0 (in addition to the normal immediate previous and after views)) is not destroyed?